# Parse XML into object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is the XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <object>
    <body>tests</body> 
    <send_results type="null" /> 
    <note_class>none</note_class> 
    <users type="list" /> 
    <title>test</title> 
    <time_sent type="null" /> 
    <image type="null" /> 
    <to_customers type="boolean">False</to_customers> 
    <time_created>2013-06-26T16:40:50</time_created> 
    <num_sends type="integer">0</num_sends> 
    <time_scheduled type="null" /> 
    <dealership>/api/v1/dealerships/10/</dealership> 
    <id type="integer">22</id> 
    <send_rate>none</send_rate> 
    <send_method>email</send_method> 
    <reply_to_email>do_not_reply@williamson-cadillac.com</reply_to_email> 
    <response_link type="null" /> 
    <to_users type="boolean">True</to_users> 
    <resource_uri>/api/v1/notifications/22/</resource_uri> 
  </object>
```

I'm trying to parse the Xml into an object...

```
       var query = from m in parsedXml.Decendants("object")
                    select new Notifications
                    {
                        Body = (string)m.Element("body"),
                        SendResults = (string)m.Element("send_results"),
                        NoteClass = (string)m.Element("note_class"),
                        Users = m.Element("users").Elements().Select(e => (string)e.Element("value")).ToList(),
                        Title = (string)m.Element("title"),
                        TimeSent = (string)m.Element("time_sent"),
                        Image = (string)m.Element("image"),
                        ToCustomers = (string)m.Element("to_customers"),
                        TimeCreated = (string)m.Element("time_created"),
                        NumSends = (string)m.Element("num_sends"),
                        TimeScheduled = (string)m.Element("time_scheduled"),
                        Dealership = (string)m.Element("dealership"),
                        Id = (string)m.Element("id"),
                        SendRate = (string)m.Element("send_rate"),
                        SendMethod = (string)m.Element("send_method"),
                        ReplyToEmail = (string)m.Element("reply_to_email"),
                        ResponseLink = (string)m.Element("response_link"),
                        ToUsers = (string)m.Element("to_users"),
                        ResourceUri = (string)m.Element("resource_uri"),
                    };
```

and I keep on getting "nothing" or "null" in the variable "query".

I can't figure this out - I've tried many different things. Thanks for you help in these matters.

Comment: Please include the code for how `parsedXml` is created

Comment: Can you compile that code? beacuse it is `Descendants` not `Decendants`

Comment: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html                                                                                  Like p.s.w.g posted, we cannot do much unless we see how it was created.  But you can click this link to check as well

Comment: Im a fan of .Elements("name") rather than .Descendants("name")

Comment: @CSharpie why are you fan of one of them? They don't do the same thing.

Comment: I know, in the past it often turned out that .Elements() was suiting peoples need better than .Descendants(). Was Jsut throwing that in, not suggestiong it.

Comment: You can't loop over `object` because `object` is your root node and you can only ever have one root node.  You will only ever get one result from your above code as John Kraft demonstrates in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code and directly pasted it into a console application. It works exactly as expected.

[image]

Is there anything else that you can show us that might have an effect on the results?

Here is the complete sample I used, in case you are doing something different...

```
string xml = 
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
  <object>
    <body>tests</body> 
    <send_results type='null' /> 
    <note_class>none</note_class> 
    <users type='list' /> 
    <title>test</title> 
    <time_sent type='null' /> 
    <image type='null' /> 
    <to_customers type='boolean'>False</to_customers> 
    <time_created>2013-06-26T16:40:50</time_created> 
    <num_sends type='integer'>0</num_sends> 
    <time_scheduled type='null' /> 
    <dealership>/api/v1/dealerships/10/</dealership> 
    <id type='integer'>22</id> 
    <send_rate>none</send_rate> 
    <send_method>email</send_method> 
    <reply_to_email>do_not_reply@williamson-cadillac.com</reply_to_email> 
    <response_link type='null' /> 
    <to_users type='boolean'>True</to_users> 
    <resource_uri>/api/v1/notifications/22/</resource_uri> 
  </object>";
var parsedXml = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var query = from m in parsedXml.Descendants("object")
            select new Notifications
            {
                Body = (string)m.Element("body"),
                SendResults = (string)m.Element("send_results"),
                NoteClass = (string)m.Element("note_class"),
                Users = m.Element("users").Elements().Select(e => (string)e.Element("value")).ToList(),
                Title = (string)m.Element("title"),
                TimeSent = (string)m.Element("time_sent"),
                Image = (string)m.Element("image"),
                ToCustomers = (string)m.Element("to_customers"),
                TimeCreated = (string)m.Element("time_created"),
                NumSends = (string)m.Element("num_sends"),
                TimeScheduled = (string)m.Element("time_scheduled"),
                Dealership = (string)m.Element("dealership"),
                Id = (string)m.Element("id"),
                SendRate = (string)m.Element("send_rate"),
                SendMethod = (string)m.Element("send_method"),
                ReplyToEmail = (string)m.Element("reply_to_email"),
                ResponseLink = (string)m.Element("response_link"),
                ToUsers = (string)m.Element("to_users"),
                ResourceUri = (string)m.Element("resource_uri"),
            };

Console.WriteLine("Number of items = {0}, {1}",query.Count(), query.FirstOrDefault().Body);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: As much as this is a good point, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's kind of the point. I suspect the issue is due to something other than what has been presented. I'm hoping the op can give more detail if he/she is still having the problem.

Comment: This should still be a comment.

Comment: I would agree... except that you can't put a screenshot in a comment. And I consider "works on my machine" as a cop out without proof.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your XML being parsed, we are taking for granted it has been done correctly. Just to be sure, you should either load it from a file or parse a string like this.

```
//Load Xml file
var document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml");

//Parse Xml 
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

If you place a breakpoint on your line starting `var query`, then when it hits check `parsedXml` to make sure it has the expected value.

Also You should really have something like this, you are currently missing a root node.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <objects>
     <object>
         ...
     <object>
  </objects>
```

Lastly, if you already have a class that this deserializes to correctly, using LINQ is not the same as deserializing. If you are just selecting into an existing class then LINQ is what you want. Be sure you are using the correct tool for the job.